# Uninstalling WSL lead to infinite Blue screen of the death loop on reboot

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, blue-screen-of-death

Yesterday I have got my new machine and after a lot of trouble I was able to install and activate Windows 10 Pro. After installing all needed drivers I have began downloading software that I used on my old machine. That lead me to installing WSL. WSL itself installed fine with Ubuntu. I could not start WSL session. So I figured I might have to reinstall it. I have tried to reboot the system but could not get into log into Windows. After many attempts I reached for completely reinstalling the whole system from scratch. I have inserted my USB flash drive with new system and storage driver because my notebook did not come with one. After installing needed driver I have tried automatic diagnostic and it has actually worked. But Ubuntu was still showing in Settings > Apps so I have uninstalled it and now I'm back again to the same Blue screen of death reboot loop and the work around does not work. How can I recover my computer if I can't even boot up windows?